# mysql select dates between

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a single mysql table called prices storing dates from and to like so:

```
id    from          to              price
1     2013-11-25    2014-01-08      55
```

the user selects a month and a year and i want it to show all results that either are from or to that month
so if the user selected either november 2013, december 2013 or january 2014 it would include the above row.

```
id    from          to              price
2     2013-10-25    2013-11-07      100
```

and if they selected either october or november 2013 it would show the above row because it starts in october and ends november.

i have tried

```
SELECT * FROM `prices`
WHERE MONTH(prices.from)<={$_SESSION['month']}
AND MONTH(prices.to)>={$_SESSION['month']}
AND YEAR(prices.to)={$_SESSION['year']}
ORDER BY prices.from ASC
```

which doesn't work i'm not sure how this can be done

Comment: I'm pretty sure that greater than and less than don't work in mysql queries, you can use `WHERE xxx BETWEEN xxx AND xxx`

Comment: What is 'doesn't work'? BTW, how do you want to deal with cases where one selected month returns 2 rows of prices?

Comment: i want to show all rows of prices found

Comment: I'm not sure how i can use BETWEEN because the user selects one month and year not a range of months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to create a date from the month and year the user selects and then use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to put your table's date column in YYYY-MM format and compare both with the YYYY-MM the user inserted.

I'm not fluent in php, but here's an example in sql (you can use any day in the str_to_date, since you will ignore it):

```sql
SELECT * FROM `prices`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(prices.`from`,"%Y-%m") <= 
   DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('01,10,2013','%d,%m,%Y'),"%Y-%m")
AND DATE_FORMAT(prices.`to`,"%Y-%m") >= 
   DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('01,10,2013','%d,%m,%Y'),"%Y-%m")
ORDER BY prices.`from` ASC
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef586/5)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "BETWEEN" instead.
example:

```
SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE MONTH(`from`) BETWEEN '10' AND '12' AND YEAR(`to`)='2013'
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this method:

```
SELECT * from prices
WHERE str_to_date('{$_SESSION['month']}-{$_SESSION['year']}','%b-%Y') BETWEEN date(prices.from) AND date(prices.to)
```

You might just want to use the correct format in the str_to_date, currently it converts the following format = Oct-2013

Check this for other formats: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date